Sharing of Printers through two different routers
I have Two Wifi epson Printers in my Office Third Floor and it is connected with second router with wifi, I need to access the printer with the main router which is in my House, Advise me how to it....the Second router is connected with cable to the main router....

Is the second router serving its own IPs, or is it in "repeater" mode? If you set any secondary routers to only server WiFi and not hand out their own IPs, usually called "repeater mode", all devices will be on the same network and accessible by all other devices on that network.
